# Slices vs harmonic functions — intuition/definitions question

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

One can identify functions on slices of the boolean  hypercube $[n] \choose d$ with harmonic multilinear functions of degree at most $d$.

I don't really understand the intuition behind the harmonic condition—for all $x_i$ , $$ \frac{\partial P}{\partial x_i} = 0,$$  and I also have some trouble with the definitions. I am using the notation as in [Filmus - Orthogonal basis for functions over a slice of the Boolean hypercube](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.0142).

Let's focus on the $d=2$ case. 
It seems to suggest that if $P=A_{ij} x_i x_j$ then $A$ is anti-symmetric. But thats means that $P=0$.
For example, 
$$(a_{12}+a_{21}) x_2 =-(a_{13}+a_{31})x_3$$
but $x_2$ and $x_3$ are independent, so we can choose whatever we want.

It seems as though on the one hand $x_i$, determines if $i$ is in the slice.
So the functional $\langle e_{\{i,j\}} , \cdot \rangle$ translates to $x_i x_j$. 
On the other hand, $x_i x_j$ is not in the space.
We do however have a natural transformation $B$ to $\chi_B$ (in the space) for every top set, but not for the set $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Is it more suitable for SE mathematics? I wasn't sure

Comment: First, you copied incorrectly the harmonicity condition, which the paper writes as the sum $$ \sum_{i= 1}^n \frac{\partial P}{\partial x_i}= 0$$ not at all that it has vanishing gradient. Applying this to the polynomial of the form $P = A_{ij} x_i x_j$ implies that $$ \sum_{j,k} (A_{jk} + A_{kj}) x_j = 0 $$ which is not the same as require $A$ to be antisymmetric! You just need $\sum_k A_{jk} + A_{kj} = 0$ for all $j$ (which is satisfied when $A$ is antisymmetric, but not necessarily so)